# How do I access parts of my Java object?

Tags: java, eclipse, object

I'm almost positive this question has been asked before, as I'm sure I'm not the first person to have this problem, but I don't know the right search words to get my answer, so if you could point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it.

I have an Object in a Java class, that when I mouse over, says:

```
variableName = Object[6]
  >[0] = "words in here"
  >[1] = "a few more words"
  >[2] = float
  >[3] = float
  >[4] = integer
  >[5] = integer
```

I want to print out "words in here" and get the value of the integer in [5].  How do I do this?  I've tried a couple of things like

```
String whatsNeeded = variableName[0];
String whatToGet = variableName.toString();
```

But neither of those get what I want.  In fact, variableName[0] gives me an error, and variableName.toString() prints [Ljava.lang.Object;@*blahblah*

Any tips on how to get the fields I want?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String whatsNeeded = variableName[0];
```

Gives you an error because you have an `Object[]` type, so `variableName[0]` has type `Object`, not `String`. You must downcast it: `String whatsNeeded = (String)variableName[0]`.

Regarding `variableName.toString()`, `toString` on an array data type doesn't work as you intend and just prints the reference in memory. You should use `Arrays.toString(variableName)` to get a proper printed value.

Looking at your comment it looks like you can't access items of `variableName` through `[]` operator. This happens because you probably assigned it to an `Object` type variable, eg:

```
Object[] array = new Object[6];
Object object = array;

array[0] // valid
object[0] // invalid, it is an array at runtime but not at compile time
```

If that's the case you must first cast it to an array:

```
Object asArray = (Object[])variableName;
String whatsNeeded = (String)asArray[0];
```

Comment: Ok so I tried casting it like you suggested, but the error that appears persists.  It says "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Object".  Does this make sense?

Comment: Probably you are not storing the array in an `Object[]` variable but in an `Object`. Check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

try casting , for example :

```
 String tmp=(String)varName[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
variableName.toString()
```

you are invoking the toString method so you need to know how it's working or you can override the method.

Now, if you want to print one element of your array, in this case the first element, you need to know the type of the object, if your program is dynamic, then you need a set of methods or only "if" sentences to verify each element of your array and finally you must do a casting on the object, for example:

```
if (variableName[0] instanceof String) {
((String)variableName[0]).toString();
}
```

I hope this information helps you.

Good luck.

Comment: That runs into the same issue as the answer above.  The problem is that it doesn't like the [] after variableName.  It looks like an array, but apparently behaves differently for the purposes of getting the values